# T-invariant linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

If U is a T-invariant subspace of dim n+1, and if there is no subspace W ⊆≠U such that T(w) ∈ W for all w ∈ W, then the set of vectors {u,T(u),T^2(u),...,T^n(u)}, u ∈ U, u ≠ 0  forms a basis for U.

To show the set of vectors forms a basis. I need to show

> 1. The set is a linearly independent set
> 2. The span of this set is U.

I am stuck at this point. How can I show the vectors in this set is linearly independent? Also, I am not sure how to show the span(set) = U. I know the dimension of this set is also n, which matches to the dimension of the subspace.
Can I claim since all the T-invariant subspaces are in U, the set of vectors span U? Thank you so much!

Edit: added u is non-zero

Comment: I think you need the assumption $\;\{0\}\neq W\lneq U\;$ there...and what is $\;u\;$ ??

Comment: Ok, **proper** must mean what I'd call "non-trivial", meaning: whatever but the zero subspace and the whole space, of course.

Comment: @DonAntonio ok thanks a lot! I will edit it and think about it.

Comment: @DonAntonio The question did not mention u clearly except u ∈ U. So I am assuming it is an element of U?

Comment: It must be, otherwise we cannot even understand what $\;Tu\;$ could possibly be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're *given* that $\;\dim U=n+1\;$ and we have $\;n+1\;$ vectors in $\;B:=\{\,u=T^0u, Tu,...,T^nu\,\}\;$ , all we have to do is to prove $\;B\;$ is *linearly independent* . So assume it isn't, and this means there's a vector in $\;B\;$ which is a linear combination of the **preceeding ones**:

$$T^mu=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}a_kT^ku:=r$$

But this then means the subspace $\;W:=\text{Span}\,\{u,Tu,...,T^{m-1}u\}\;$ is $\;T\,-$ invariant, since

$$x\in W\implies x=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}b_iT^iu\;\;\implies\;\;Tx=b_0Tu+\ldots+b_{m-1}T^mu=$$

$$=b_0Tu+\ldots+b_{m-2}T^{m-1}u+b_{m-1}r\in W\ldots!$$

This means either $\;W=\{0\}\;$ or $\;W=U\;$, and we're done (fill in details...)

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. I think there is a typo on the second last sentence, where b_2Tu should be b_0Tu? Also, another approach can be showing that B is the span of U given the dimensions are both n. Would that be possible to do? Thanks again!

Comment: @LiseLöwe Typo corrected, thanks. To show span$\,B=U\;$ seems to be much harder. In fact, I'm not even sure how to proceed...

Comment: @Donaontonio Sorry I have a quick question regarding to your answer. I understood your subspace W, but isn't W a subset of U? Because m-1 cannot be larger than n-1, so the range of W is within U?

Comment: @L Yes, of course: $\;W\;$ is a subset, and a subspace, of $\;U\;$ . Everything happens within $\;U\;$ .